# How can I access the HTML element selected (monthpicker) in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using a monthpicker plugin for HTML page http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Minimal-jQuery-Month-Picker-Plugin-Simple-MonthPicker.
I am able to download and run it as expected. However, I have issues in rendering the month that was selected by the user. 
My HTML code is :

```
<body> 
<input id="demo-1" type="text" />
                <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
                <script src="monthpicker.js"></script>
                <script>
                    $("#demo-1").Monthpicker({
                        dateFormat: 'yymmdd',
                        onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
                            var dateStringForApi = $(this).val();
                            alert(dateStringForApi);
                        }
                        });
                </script>
</body>
```

There's no alert when I select the month and year. 
Can anyone tell me where am I going wrong ?
Please find attached the image for the more details. [image]

*PLNKR DEMO*
http://embed.plnkr.co/wui6hRg4E4gbAWPqbr6y/

Comment: An image is not much use. Post your code on eg. jsfiddle. We need a [mcve]

Comment: The documentation say you need to get it via `$("#demo-1").val()`

Comment: Plunkr link is updated in the Question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(this).val();` is undefined. `this` is the MonthPicker object in this scope which has no value attribute if you inspect it.

Using `$("#demo-1").val()` will return the value you are looking for.

Comment: This unfortunately does not works. 
Please see my entire code here :
http://embed.plnkr.co/wui6hRg4E4gbAWPqbr6y/

Comment: Well that's because you've changed the code from what you posted before, you are trying to get the value before it's even been set. See [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/2DW8uqTa3opgqqN04jAx?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks a lot spaceman !
THat worked. Please post it as answer.